# how to use variable inside function

Tags: java

Sorry for asking such a basic question, but I just can't figure it out and I have no idea how to search for it.

I have the following code:

```
letters = new ArrayList<JButton>();
String[] abc = new String[] {"A", "Á", "B", "C", "D", "E", "É", "F", "G", "H", "I", "Í", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "Ó", "Ö", "Ő", "P",
        "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "Ú", "Ü", "Ű", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };
for (Object o: abc)
{
    letters.add(new JButton((String)o));
    int i = letters.size() - 1;
    letters.get(i).setBounds(i%10 * 60 + 40, 350 + ((i / 10) * 50), 55, 45);
    letters.get(i).addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    });
    mF.add(letters.get(i));
}
```

As you can see, I have a for loop and I'd like to use its variable 'o' inside the function. How can I do that? It says:

```
java: local variable o is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
```

What exactly does this mean?

Comment: make it final, `for (final Object o: abc)`

Comment: Define one final object and use that object to iterate loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the for loop, write like this:

```
for (final Object o: abc)
{
    ...
```

So the compiler knows that the object `o` will not change, i.e. you will not assign a new value to it with `=`.

Answer (score 3):

It means that to be accessed in an inner class, the compiler has to be sure that this variable  cannot be modified, as the code will be probably be executed asynchronously. change `for (Object o: abc)` to `for (final String o: abc)`

Answer (score 2):

you can not perform `System.out.println(o);`

as o is not defined as final.

```
for (final Object o: abc)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
letters.get(i).addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
});
```

Is creating an inner class, simply make the foreach loop use `final Object o`.

Comment: it is not the array instantiation that is creating an inner class, it is the `new ActionListener ...`

Comment: quite sure, yes. `new String[] {"A", ....}` is just creating an instance, not a Class, `new ActionListener(...` does as he is overriding `actionPerformed` method

Comment: @gma you are aboslutely right, I was thinking of double brace initialization

Answer (score 1):

You are using an anonymous inner class, and from within those classes you may access final variables declared outside.
Here's an example which will not work because message is not final:

```
public void myMethod() {
    String message = "You can't see me";

    new SomeInterface() {

        //SomeInterface declares this method:
        public void someMethod() {
            System.out.println(message); //this will not compile
        }
    };
}
```

But this will work because message is final:

```
public void myOtherMethod() {
    final String message = "You can see me now!";

    new SomeInterface() {

        //SomeInterface declares this method:
        public void someMethod() {
            System.out.println(message); //this will work!
        }
    };
}
```